# Getting count of objects in a Hibernate Criteria Query to display in JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have some Hibernate entities that I want to group by `paramType` and display the parameter type. Here is the `controller.getAnalyticsCount()` method:

```
public List<Analytic> getAnalyticCount() {
    Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Analytic.class);
    return criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                                       .add( Projections.rowCount())
                                       .add( Projections.groupProperty("paramType")).list();
}
```

Now, in displaying in JSF, the following works, but prints each objects:

```
<ui:repeat var="foo" value="#{controller.getAnalyticsCount()}">
    #{foo}
</ui:repeat>
```

How do I print the actual counts? Isn't the other fields of the grouped by object available to me? I have also tried `.add( Projections.rowCount(),'counts')` and #{foo.counts}`. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) seems to be very light in this respect.

PS: Actually, the return type is possibly the reason, but what exactly is the return type in this case, it is no longer of type `List<Analytic>` I guess.

Comment: Show us the code of the method getAnalyticsCount.

Comment: OK, I have added the method's return line and type. I suspect the problem is in the return type then. Actually it is longer than this, I have some further criteria added, but I believe those lines are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This criteria query won't return instances of Analytic. It will return a list of `Object[]`. Each `Object[]` in the list contains 2 elements:

1. the count, as an Integer or a Long (it has changed recently. I cast to Number and ask its int value to be safe.
2. the paramType

You should of course create a list of bean instances from this lits of Object[], and use these beans in your view.